# GetProcAddress with 0 as lpProcName

Tags: ida, binary-analysis, pe32

I'm reversing a 32bit binary for a challenge I got at a college lab and I'm having a hard time trying to understand the intent of the asm code.

The binary is a 10 level reversing game where you get no info at the start and have to figure out everything on your way on building a flag at the end.

Basically it uses a lot of encryption techniques to derive strings from integer values (as far as I got). I figured out some of the imports it uses like `LoadLibraryA`, `GetProcAddress` (I guess it uses them later on somehow).

Where I'm currently stuck is the asm code calls `GetProcAddress` with `kernel32.dll` handle as the first argument and `0`( or `NULL` I guess ) as the second argument. The return I get is then used to make some integer division. My problem is that I get `NULL` from the `GetProcAddress` call and then when hitting the `idiv`, I get a Division By 0 Exception thrown.

Here's a picture: [image]

On `0x00401A85` `eax` is `0`(`NULL`). Any ideas on how to solve this? What's the idea behind passing `0`(`NULL`) as the second parameter?

Thanks!

Comment: It might be an (0)ordinal number, but it might thrown exception by dividing to zero, in that case, check if there is an SEH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out it was just a trick inserted in the code to distract us. What can I say, it was very successful haha. I ended up asking my teacher and he told me to try and avoid getting into that part of the code and after that I was able to see my mistake. Definitely learned something by falling into that trap

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft Docs: GetProcAddress](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress):

> ```
> lpProcName
> ```
>
> The function or variable name, or the function's ordinal value. If
>   this parameter is an **ordinal value**, it must be in the low-order
>   word; the high-order word must be zero.

Here the second parameter is an *ordinal value*. This may be done intentionally to hide the function name that the program imports. According to [Wikipedia: DLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library):

> Each function exported by a DLL is identified by a numeric ordinal and
>   optionally a name. Likewise, functions can be imported from a DLL
>   either by ordinal or by name. The ordinal represents the position of
>   the function's address pointer in the DLL Export Address table. It is
>   common for **internal functions** to be exported by ordinal only. For
>   most Windows API functions only the names are preserved across
>   different Windows releases; the ordinals are **subject to change**.

To get the function name first see the DLL file name in `LoadLibrary()` or `LoadLibraryEx()`. Open that DLL in IDA. Go to View Menu > Open subviews > Exports. Or use `dumpbin /exports mydll.dll` command to list all the exported functions and their corresponding ordinals. See [dumpbin reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference) for further details.

Comment: kernel32.dll typically has an `Ordinal Base` of 1, which means an ordinal of zero would be invalid.

Comment: Yes, @joshpoley, that's what I also found.. And then division crashes my program. I'm not sure yet if I'm on the right path. I asked my teacher for some guidance and he told me to look more into error handling and debugger evasion techniques which I found an example here: https://www.autosectools.com/Anti-Debugging-With-Exceptions.pdf

Comment: Using exceptions may be a way to detect debuggers. However, you should have the possibility to pass the exception to the application when debugger receives it. I would give it a try, if such anti-debugging technique is present in code you are analysing. That way, the application will receive an exception as it expects and won't realise that it's being debugged.

Comment: Turned out it was just a dead end inserted in the code as a trick to "eat" out time out.. My teacher gave me a tip into trying not to get in that area of the code and I was able to solve it after that